# Group rows in maximum 2 rows per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like the following
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/149382/2

And the result should be like the following

```
TripGroup  Grouper1      Grouper2      Date         Hour              Code    Description
1          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   00:01:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
1          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   00:03:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
2          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   05:45:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
2          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   07:30:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
3          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   05:55:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
3          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   07:30:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
4          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   14:45:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
4          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   15:40:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
```

My problem is when 2 GARAG start before the RET

All groups should have one line starting with GARAG and one with RET

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: Post not just link actual data

Comment: In the example I used a table, but on the real case I'm using a select from a long query, on which I have a PK, but not NEED on the end result.

Comment: Ok, is there another column you can add to this query to sort the rows?

Comment: That's the only rows I have. Only the date and time to sort.

Comment: please show us a sample where the is "2 GARAG start before the RET"  and what is the issue and expected result. Thanks.

Comment: The sample is on the sqlfiddle link on the TripGroup 2 and 3

Comment: Link not good enough.  -1

Comment: I have the issue on the sqlfiddle link and the expected result on this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is want you want. You can also change Description in where clause to Code. But if not, let me know and will look for the answer. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
 SELECT row_number() over (partition by Grouper1, Grouper2 order by Date, Hour) as TripGroup,
  Grouper1,
  Grouper2,
  Date,
  Hour,
  Code,
  Description
FROM FOO
where Description = 'GARAG EXTRA'
UNION ALL
SELECT row_number() over (partition by Grouper1, Grouper2 order by Date, Hour) as TripGroup,
  Grouper1,
  Grouper2,
  Date,
  Hour,
  Code,
  Description
FROM FOO
where Description = 'RET  EXTRA/GARAG'
order by TripGroup, Description;

Result:
TripGroup  Grouper1      Grouper2      Date         Hour              Code    Description
1          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   00:01:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
1          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   00:03:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
2          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   05:45:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
2          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   07:30:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
3          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   05:55:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
3          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   07:30:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
4          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   14:45:00.0000000  3962X1  GARAG EXTRA
4          6EA579BEA901  58639247D5CB  2018-02-03   15:40:00.0000000  3962X2  RET  EXTRA/GARAG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one line starting with GARAG and one with RET, how about this?

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by grouper1, grouper2, date, datepart(hour, hour), description
                                order by date, hour
                               ) as seqnum 
      from foo f
     ) f
where seqnum = 1
order by grouper1, grouper2, date, datepart(hour, hour),
         (case when description like 'GARAG%' then 1 else 2 end)
```